# Need help in optimising moving window entropy calculations

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numpy-ndarray, entropy, parallelism-amdahl

I am trying to calculate the entropy of 3D patches with sliding windows from a larger 3D array. I can't seem to find a way of optimising the code to run with any reasonable speed.

My current working approach uses nested for loops taking each coord of the larger array and calculating the entropy of the patch with that coord as the starting point.

I'd really like to be able to run this operation in parallel but can't seem to get **`pool.apply()`** working, is it possible to run this in parallel?

Here is my working code:

```
def get_entropy_of_block(data):
    value,counts = np.unique(data, return_counts=True)
    entropy_of_block = entropy(value, counts)
    if np.isnan(entropy_of_block):
        entropy_of_block = 0
    return entropy_of_block


def output_entropy_versions(mask, window = 5):    
        mask = np.pad(mask, (0,window - 2), 'edge')
        blocks = view_as_windows(mask, (window,window,window),step=1)
        entropy_mask = np.zeros(shape=(blocks.shape[0], blocks.shape[1], blocks.shape[2]))
        for x in range(blocks.shape[0]):
            print(x)
            for y in range(blocks.shape[1]):
                for z in range(blocks.shape[2]):
                    entropy_mask[x,y,z] = get_entropy_of_block(blocks[x,y,z,:,:])
        return entropy_mask
```

And here is the parallel attempt

```
def output_entropy_versions_parallel(mask, window = 5):    

        mask = np.pad(mask, (0,window - 2), 'edge')
        blocks = view_as_windows(mask, (window,window,window),step=1)
        entropy_mask = np.zeros(shape=(blocks.shape[0], blocks.shape[1], blocks.shape[2]))
        for x in range(blocks.shape[0]):
            print(x)
            for y in range(blocks.shape[1]):
                    res = [pool.apply(get_entropy_of_block, args = (blocks[x,y,z,:,:])) for z in range(blocks.shape[2])]
                    entropy_mask[x,y,:] = res
        return entropy_mask
```

Running this I get the following:

```
<ipython-input-10-8c3d4ca9d313> in output_entropy_versions(mask, window)
     24                 print(x)
     25                 for y in range(blocks.shape[1]):
---> 26                         res = [pool.apply(get_entropy_of_block, args = (blocks[x,y,z,:,:])) for z in range(blocks.shape[2])]
     27                         entropy_mask[x,y,:] = res
     28             return entropy_mask

> <ipython-input-10-8c3d4ca9d313> in get_entropy_of_block(data)
     10 def get_entropy_of_block(data):
     11         value,counts = np.unique(data, return_counts=True)
---> 12         entropy_of_block = entropy(value, counts)
     13         if np.isnan(entropy_of_block):
     14             entropy_of_block = 0

E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py in entropy(pk, qk, base)
   2505     """
   2506     pk = asarray(pk)
-> 2507     pk = 1.0*pk / np.sum(pk, axis=0)
   2508     if qk is None:
   2509         vec = entr(pk)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'generator'
```

Comment: can you give some context from the stacktrace? seems like a `generator` needs to be made into a `numpy.ndarray` at some point

Comment: `E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py in entropy(pk, qk, base)
   2505     """
   2506     pk = asarray(pk)
-> 2507     pk = 1.0*pk / np.sum(pk, axis=0)
   2508     if qk is None:
   2509         vec = entr(pk)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'generator'`

Comment: looks like `pool.apply` is returning a `generator`?

Comment: I've just realised, I have copied the wrong 'working code' *(doh)*,  "for z in range(blocks.shape[2]): entropy_mask[x,y,z] = get_entropy_of_block(blocks[x,y,z,:,:])" - replaces the pool.apply

Comment: please update your code to reflect and put the stack trace for the relevant code in the question

Comment: Ok  - all done, thanks (sorry, newb)

Comment: `value` is a generator, check your data types